# Seeking Suggestions for Automating a Smart TV App in a CI/CD Pipeline with Broad Device Coverage

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, appium, uiautomation, cicd

We have a client who wishes to automate their Smart TV app within a CI/CD pipeline and aims to cover as many devices as possible. Currently, I am the sole QA on this project and am exploring setup ideas to meet their requirements.

As of now, I have identified three potential options:

1. Utilizing services like BrowserStack or LambdaTest, which, although paid, only cater to 3-4 devices, hence not appearing very feasible.
2. Investing in hardware that facilitates connections to real devices for remote access and control, however, this could incur significant expenses, and thus may not be a feasible option either.
3. Leveraging publicly provided drivers from each Smart TV to access customer-facing APIs. This approach, while potentially viable, lacks a unified method for different TVs and might become unwieldy.

Has anyone had experience with the third option, or are there other alternatives or ideas that I might have overlooked?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SQA stack exchange. You'd get a better outcome if you asked a question that was less opinion-based (see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for more information). You might try asking for advantages and disadvantages of each approach or criteria to use to make your decision. You could also try https://club.ministryoftesting.com/ (Disclaimer: I am a member), which has a more traditional forum format

Comment: Welcome to the community! I think we need more info. What's the tech stack the Smart TV app is written in? Is it just a web app that runs on a TV? Are you constrained to testing on a TV only? Can it also run on mobile devices and laptops? Is there a mobile app part that controls the TV app? Can it work with a TV remote? Are there APIs that you can use to simulate a remote? Does it have to work for any TV? Are devices like Roku need to be tested?